# get a deeper element which satisfies the condition

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

```
    "address_components": [
    {
        "long_name": "8",
        "short_name": "8",
        "types": [
            "street_number"
        ]
    },
    {
        "long_name": "Promenade",
        "short_name": "Promenade",
        "types": [
            "route"
        ]
    },
    {
        "long_name": "Cheltenham",
        "short_name": "Cheltenham",
        "types": [
            "postal_town"
        ]
    },
    {
        "long_name": "Gloucestershire",
        "short_name": "Gloucestershire",
        "types": [
            "administrative_area_level_2",
            "political"
        ]
    },
    {
        "long_name": "England",
        "short_name": "England",
        "types": [
            "administrative_area_level_1",
            "political"
        ]
    },
    {
        "long_name": "United Kingdom",
        "short_name": "GB",
        "types": [
            "country",
            "political"
        ]
    },
    {
        "long_name": "GL50 1LR",
        "short_name": "GL50 1LR",
        "types": [
            "postal_code"
        ]
    }
],
```

Need to get the postal_code value, which is the value of long_name with types=postal_code. In the api result,it seems types itself is an array. Looping and finding out is a bad method. also array_search also don't work. Can anybody help me.

Comment: As you are saying "array_search also don't work" please share your try ?

Comment: I suggest to use collection. Or please share what is the source of above data ?

Comment: It's thirdy party api given by client

Comment: Means you are getting this in ajax response ? in JavaScript ?

Comment: php code , json response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just loop through the array and find an item with the postal code:

```
foreach ($arr["address_components"] as $item) {
    if (in_array("postal_code", $item["types"])) {
        echo $item["long_name"];
    }
}
```

I'll leave error handling to you.

Comment: As OP is saying "Looping and finding out is a bad method", please clear his/her doubt.

Comment: @NikleshRaut "Looping and finding out is a bad method". To clear any doubt it's not a bad method.

Comment: Yeah I agree. this method is fine

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_filter` to iterate over array without looping:

```
$postal_code_arrays = array_filter($arr, function($a){
  if(!isset($a['types'])) return false;

  // Or you can use another condition. i.e: if array only contains postal code
  if(in_array('postal_code', $a['types'])) {  
    return true;
  }
  
  return false;
});
```

This will return array which only contains last one in your array:

```
[
    [
        "long_name" => "GL50 1LR",
        "short_name" => "GL50 1LR",
        "types" => [
            "postal_code"
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: FYI, you can probably simplify it down to `return in_array('postal_code', $a['types'] ?? []);`. If its not set you get an empty array - and then its not in the array, returns false, otherwise it returns true.

Answer (score 0):

Try array_filter

```
$postCode = array_filter($arr["address_components"], function($v) {
    return in_array("postal_code", $v["types"]);
})[0]['long_name'];
```